# Modifying cypher query with additional properties and labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a system whereby I will be handed in cypher queries to do specific operations (e.g. create a new node) as part of a pipeline.

The question I have, is that I would like to add additional properties and labels to this query that has been handed in to a process before it sends it off to the database (Neo4j) , but I would like to avoid a complex string parsing/update exercise.

For example, I may be given something like this:

`CREATE (:testnode {tag_str: \"CgESpOVg\"})`

But I want to add additional system (i.e. source process outside of the databse) provided properties and labels to this node creation *before* we hand it off to Neo4J.

Is there a way to do this without having to modify the original query, but instead just "bolting" on to it at the end?

As an obviously nonworking example, something like as follows?

`CREATE (newnode:testnode {tag_str: \"mytag\"}) + <additional property foobar: usefuldata on variable new node>`

The WITH clause sounds promising, but thus far I have not been able to make it work.

Comment: You dont use + but a comma when defining a new property

Comment: Yup, I know, the intent of that example above was for pseudo-code of what I'm trying to do, not a valid query. But good catch though.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please be specific about (1) how you intend to specify the canned properties to be added, (2) what should be done if the canned properties overlap with the input properties, and (3) how you will specify which nodes and/or relationships need to have added canned data. It would also be helpful if you provided a more concrete use case, as the question is currently too broad.

Comment: Hi @cybersam, the question is broad because the solution is as well.  The intent is to add arbitrary properties at the end of the query, without modifying the original query string beyond appending to it. I do believe there's a potential solution by including a variable in the initial create to refer to in subsequent SET calls that can be appended.  I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowing a string to be appended to the original query string before submitting, and there is a variable declared in the node, you can use the `SET` clause:

```
CREATE (newnode:testnode {tag_str: \"mytag\"})
SET newnode.property1 = value1,
    newnode.property2 = value2 ...
```

Comment: Was the solution I ended up as at well. The key element is that I want to keep any string modifications at the end, and simple as possible, and the bounds of my problem do allow me to ask inputs have a consistent variable name on node creation...

Answer (score 0):

You can create [APOC triggers](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/background-operations/triggers/) to perform additional processing whenever a node or relationship is created or updated.

Comment: This isn't _quite_ what I need, what I'm asking needs to occur before the query is issued to the target database. Its ultimately modifying the string that the query is in, but trying to figure out how to do it without requiring that I modify it "in the middle" if that makes sense.